# Output of Gen.choose() and .oneOf()

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

When running the below test, `Gen()` gets printed out for both `println` statements.

Based on the ScalaCheck [docs](http://scalacheck.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/1.9/doc/api/org/scalacheck/Gen%24.html), I would've expected the output to be:

> (number, number)
>
> "Hello" or "World"

```
class TestScalaCheck extends FlatSpec {

    @author first test - https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/wiki/User-Guide
    "a test" should "print out Gen.choose(1, 100)" in {
        val myGen = for {
          n <- Gen.choose(10,20)
          m <- Gen.choose(2*n, 500)
        } yield (n,m)

        println(myGen)

        val c = Gen.oneOf("Hello", "World")
        println(c)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Gen[T]` is a generator of values (of type `T`), and this is the type of both `myGen` and `c` above. If you want to print out example values of what the generators can produce (wrapped as an Option), try `println(myGen.sample)` and `println(c.sample)`.

Comment: Thanks. Should the docs include the `sample` function?http://scalacheck.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/1.9/doc/api/org/scalacheck/Gen$.html

Comment: That's the `object`, look at the `trait` http://scalacheck.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/1.9/doc/api/org/scalacheck/Gen.html

Comment: Please note, ScalaCheck 1.9 is a bit outdated by now. For the current version, see http://www.scalacheck.org/download.html. For links to current documentation, see http://www.scalacheck.org/documentation.html